# unable to run exe created in Qt 5.3 on different windows machine

Tags: qt5.3

I am facing issues to run .exe files created in Qt 5.3 on different windows system. I have included all the .dll files. The issue is that on the latest system with graphics card support the application runs without any issues but on older systems it just gives blanck screen.

I suspect that this has something to do with openGL support for the system.

Is there a way where I can make sure that the application runs without any glitches on all the systems?
Or is it possible to have an application created without oprnGL support needed ?

Hoping to hear some solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

Following is the error I get when I run the code

```
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebuffer'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindFramebufferARB'
```

and here is the screenshot of the way the screen looks
[image: screenshot]

**NOTE :** 
Please note that when I run the .exe on a new system with updated graphics, the screens looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

**Did you include any OpenGL headers in your Qt Project?**

Because if you did then there is obviously going to be a dependency on OpenGL for each system and if one of them cannot support this then you either need to decrease the minimum version of GL you are using **or** remove these headers altogether. It is also worth noting that no matter how hard you try - you will never get the same version of OpenGL to run across every piece of hardware without having to change *something*.

**Did you add the QtOpenGL module?**

From what is sounds like, you are not using OpenGL in your application. If this is true then you should remove this module from your *.pro* file and it should remove the dependency.

I hope this answers your question. If not, could you provide a little more detail because your question was slightly vague.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply. I haven't used QtOpenGL module in my .pro file. As of now this are the modules I have used QT += qml quick core xml QT += widgets and i have updated the question. Hope thats lil useful